# SSI Error with <!#--include virtual="file.html" --> [an error occurred when processing this directive]

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, ssi

So I am learning to properly use SSI and have done so successfully on one site. On a new site I am building on the same server I am getting the error [an error occurred when processing this directive] when trying to use the tag  I have verified that SSI is enabled by using SSI to display the time and date with no problem. I have also verified spelling, and that the directory and file are there on the server. Not sure what is wrong, can SSI be partly enabled (allowing me to display the time with  but not allowing include virtual)? Am I missing something obvious? Thanks guys!

[Link to live test.](http://christianstest.info/TestingServers/ComeRestTest/index.html)

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

<!--#include virtual="/ssi/navbar.html" -->
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<!--#echo var="DATE_LOCAL" -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SSI tag includes `/ssi/navbar.html`. Since that begins with `/`, it is parsed as a full path based at the server's document root.

http://christianstest.info/ssi/navbar.html

However, that's a `404 Not Found`. I assume you are trying to include this:

http://christianstest.info/TestingServers/ComeRestTest/ssi/navbar.html

You probably just need to remove the leading `/` in the SSI tag. `virtual` specifies a URL path relative to the current page, but you are pointing it to the root directory of the server.

```
<!--#include virtual="ssi/navbar.html" -->
```

Comment: Yup, for some reason removing the leading slash did not fix it, but putting in the full file path "/TestingServers/ComeRestTest/ssi/navbar.html" did. Not sure why removing the slash did not work (I tried that before as well). I used SSI on another site that was in it's root folder, so I got into the habit of putting the leading slash in, as this site is on my testing server and in another directory that is what screwed me up. Thanks!